# jquery ajax get Set-cookie from response header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am not getting Set-Cookie value from response header. Value throw null

[image]

my code below

```
$.ajax({
    url: ip_add + '/' + reqUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: req_data,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    },

    success: function (res, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {      
        var cookietoSet = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
        alert(cookietoSet);
    },
    cache: false, 
});
```

Comment: screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGm3E.png

Comment: please refer screen shot